# prove that $P (n) = P (2n, n)$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $P (n)$ be the number of ways to express n as a sum of positive integers, and $P (n, m)$ the number of ways to express n as the sum of exactly m positive integers. Prove that $P (n) = P (2n, n)$.

I came across this problem, but I am in doubt about the validity.

Counterexample:

$P (2) = 1$ and $P (4,2) = 2$

Comment: I reckon that $P(2)=2$: indeed $P(n)=2^{n-1}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: I think for the purposes of this problem, a sum is allowed to have only one term. So $2 = 2$ and $2 = 1+1$.

Comment: By a Ferrers diagram, $P(2n,n)$ is just the number of partitions of $2n$ such that the largest part is equal to $n$. Hence we can always remove this $n$ and get a partition of $n$. (Too sketchy for an answer so I'll just leave it here.)

Comment: But $2+0=2$ and $0$ is not a positive number

Comment: @Helen $0$ is not positive but the partition is just $2$, not $2+0$

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think the comment by @EdwardH about Ferrers diagram completely answers the question.  Here I present a more "elementary" view:

$n$ expressed as a sum of positive numbers means a multiset $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k\}$ where:

- $n = a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k$
- each $a_i > 0$
- we allow multiple occurrences of the same integer, e.g. $a_1 = a_2$
- we allow the full range $1 \le k \le n$, i.e. a "sum" of one term is allowed ($n = n$ is such a sum)

Now you can pad this size-$k$ multiset with $n-k$ zeros so that the new multiset has $n$ terms, each term non-negative.  Then you add $1$ to every term, and lo and behold, you have $2n$ expressed as a sum of exactly $n$ terms, each term being positive.

The process is reversible, hence bijective, so $P(n) = P(2n,n)$.